# Ionic v4 menu only works when router-outlet has the main attribute

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, router-outlet

I'm building an app with ionic v4 the first time and I want to include a side menu.

For testing reasons, I first put it inside of the app.component.html but I couldn't let it swipe out or in.

So I saw in the documentation, that they added the `main` attribute on the `ion-router-outlet` but as far as I read: it is not documented anywhere.

I don't know, why I'd have to add this, to make it actually work.

Source: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu

`<ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>`

So I came across this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/router-outlet#properties where basically the component gets explained BUT

this property isn't documented at all. I can't find it.

So to everyone: Do I need to add this and when: why?

My menu is pretty basic but I print it out below, so you guys can see what i've build.

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-menu menuId="sideMenu" swipeGesture="true">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-button slot="start">
          <img alt="logo" src="../assets/logo.svg">
        </ion-button>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>Attack</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Defence</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Feedback</ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
  <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `main` attribute is a custom attribute that has no function by it self. Other components may rely on it. `ion-menu` will attach classes to the component that matches the `contentId` OR if this is not set with the element that has the `main` attribute.

You can see this by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/menu/menu.tsx) :

```
const content = this.contentId !== undefined
  ? this.doc.getElementById(this.contentId)
  : parent && parent.querySelector && parent.querySelector('[main]');

if (!content || !content.tagName) {
  // requires content element
  console.error('Menu: must have a "content" element to listen for drag events on.');
  return;
}
this.contentEl = content as HTMLElement;

// add menu's content classes
content.classList.add('menu-content');
```

To put it another way, you don't have to set the `main` attribute if you instead set an id on `ion-content` (just not the one inside `ion-menu`). You can also set the id on `ion-router-outlet` which will be the same thing as setting the `main` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for this question.

I find it absolutely absurd that ionic fails to document the `main` attribute, a very important aspect of ion-menu.  Nothing worse than bad docs.

Cheers