# When add <ion-router-outlet> to my page, all buttons stop working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I decided to put a side menu in my page, following the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu) I should insert the `<ion-router-outlet>` tag in this page or else the menu won't activate. The problem is, when I insert this tag all my buttons don't work anymore. Neither the click function nor the button click animation work.

I was originally using `<ion-menu-button` tag to toggle the menu, so I tried to toggle by the function: `menuController.toggle()`, but this don't work and even so I need the `<ion-router-outlet>` to activate the menu.

Without the tag I receive an error:

> Menu: must have a "content" element to listen for drag events on.

**My code:**

```html
<ion-content>
    <ion-menu side="end">
        <ion-header>
            <ion-toolbar color="primary">
                <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
            </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item *ngIf="userAccess == 'all'" href="randomHrefLink" target="_blank">
                    randomMenuItem
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>

    <ion-list>  

        <ion-item *ngIf="userAccess == 'all' || userAccess == 'randomItem'">
            <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
                <img src="assets/thumbs/randomThumbnail.jpg">
            </ion-thumbnail>
            <ion-label>
                <h2>randomItem</h2>
                <p>randomDate</p>
            </ion-label>        
            <ion-button clear slot="end" (click)="randomFunction();">buttonWithProblem</ion-button>
        </ion-item>

        ...

        <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>

    </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

---

**Additional information:**

- There is another page with the `<ion-router-outlet main>` and other
  menus, I tried to remove them, but everything remains the same. In this
  same page I tried to replicate the problem, I added a button with
  some random function just to see if this problem was in one page
  alone or in all of them. Sadly this same bug happened in that page
  too;
- Some click functions work inside the menu, only the outside buttons don't;
- Tried to add a menuId attribute to the `<ion-menu>` tag, but nothing changed too;
- Tried to implement the `(click)` function in the  tag, didn't work too;
- Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53671879/7123439), I tried to add a `contentId` attribute in the `<ion-menu>` tag and refer this to the `<ion-router-outlet>`, nothing changed;
- With [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55855787/7123439) I can see the previous error reason, but could not identify the why the buttons/functions are not working;
- Tried this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57281040/7123439) in a related SO answer, but can't see any difference also.
- I created a [stackblitz](https://ionic-4-template-ruzdzk.stackblitz.io/home) to reproduce this problem more easily, but to my frustration it worked fine there. (The menu icon is not showing in the top right corner, but it's working. I got an ionic 4 template online, so ignore the other pages). So I see that this problem is happening only in my project, if anyone have an ideia why please comment.
- I tried to recreate this problem in other project, same Ionic version, but the problem occurred there too.
- Tested in Android and browser

---

**System info:**

- Ionic CLI : 5.4.4
- NodeJS : v10.16.3

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve this problem, but I achieved the same goal using [Ionic's Action Sheet](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/action-sheet).

Ex:

```js
async function presentActionSheet() {

  const actionSheet = document.createElement('ion-action-sheet');

  actionSheet.header = "Albums";
  actionSheet.buttons = [{
    text: 'Delete',
    role: 'destructive',
    icon: 'trash',
    handler: () => {
      console.log('Delete clicked');
    }
  }, {
    text: 'Share',
    icon: 'share',
    handler: () => {
      console.log('Share clicked');
    }
  }, {
    text: 'Play (open modal)',
    icon: 'arrow-dropright-circle',
    handler: () => {
      console.log('Play clicked');
    }
  }, {
    text: 'Favorite',
    icon: 'heart',
    handler: () => {
      console.log('Favorite clicked');
    }
  }, {
    text: 'Cancel',
    icon: 'close',
    role: 'cancel',
    handler: () => {
      console.log('Cancel clicked');
    }
  }];
  document.body.appendChild(actionSheet);
  return actionSheet.present();
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24817284)

Comment: Well, it does not answer the question, that is why I don't accepted this answer. It's more like an alternative method to achieve the same goal, but it does not solve the initial problem. The link provided is the lasted documentation about the Ionic's Action Sheet, which can accessed easily just by googling this exact words. I didn't put an example because it's a basic application and there are thousands of examples out there including the documentation.